# Pre-Processing/Sanitizing Twitter data

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter, mapreduce

I need to pre-process the raw twitter data sets (around 1 GB of text file). Upon pre-processing (which involves removing stop words, special symbols, URLs), i would be performing Indexing on them using lucene.

Could any of you please suggest the best way to go about sanitizing the tweets?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
60730027    6298443824  thank you echo park. you've changed A LOT, but as long as I'm getting paid to make you move, I'm still with it! 2009-12-03 02:54:10
60730027    6297282530  fat Albert Einstein goin in right now over here!!!  2009-12-03 01:35:22
60730027    6283122724  SATURDAY NIGHT AT THE TAVERN:  http://yfrog.com/4aka3cj 2009-12-02 16:21:40
60730027    6283105517  FRIDAY NIGHT AT THE GRIFFIN: http://yfrog.com/3glqzj    2009-12-02 16:21:04
```

The first column number corresponds to the user location. However, I am not sure about what the second column number corresponds to.

For Sanitizing the data, I would replace the user location codes with the city names, remove the time stamps, remove stop characters, urls etc.

Please suggest on how to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share a few example data for clarity(they are json I guess), and what's your plan. Otherwise you'll get only opinion based answers if any.

Comment: Hi @blackSmith , i have update it.

Comment: How many `user location code` are possible ? in the order of 6E8 ?

Comment: @blackSmith there are around 400 unique location codes present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need is joining on the location code column to replace them with city names. 
Since number of `locationCode-city` tupples(mappings) are relative small(~400), you can do a map-side join.

First add the mapping file to the cache before the job submission. Depending on the Hadoop version use:

```
// prior to 2.2.0
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(path/cityCode_NameMappings.txt).toUri(), conf);

//OR 2.2.0 onwards. DistributedCache is deprecated 
job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());
```

Retrieve it in Mapper's `setup` method using :

```
Path[] cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);

// OR
Path[] cacheFiles = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
```

Identify the file by its name, read it and put contents in a static `HashMap<code,name>` and use it to replace codes in the incoming lines of actual twitter data file in the `map` method. This same strategy can be followed for replacing the second column(currently out of scope) when number of possible mappings are relatively small.

Finally to select only the body of the actual tweet, regex and simple string operations seems to be enough. Now you have two options :

1. Use a Reducer class to do the text extraction. This way code replacement 
      and tweet body extraction will be in separate abstractions.
2. Do the processing in the Mapper itself and set the number of reducers to zero. 
      This will be a map-only job and will certainly run faster although it looks 
      messy a bit.

The choice is yours. Again if your city-code mappings were large in numbers, you had no options but to do a reduce-side join. That would be relatively 
complex to implement.

**Second Thought :** If you have liberty to choose another tool for indexing other than raw Lucene, I suggest you to use ElasticSearch(built on Lucene).
Then you could utilize Hive to do the joining and use Hive-ES integration to load the data into index. Still you had to do the text processing(perhaps a hive serde could do the trick).